# How to calculate subtotals on grouped rows using Knockout in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to calculate sub totals for grouped row for selected rows, I am able to calculate but on every change total calculating by looping through all the elements. Can anybody suggest how to add or subtract row value from grouped row. If we have huge number of rows and select all is taking more time. here is sample code of mine http://jsfiddle.net/Srinivasa/PAtSd/2/

Comment: This is a good question. I don't see an obvious way to improve on what you currently have. Maybe if I give it a +1 someone smarter than myself can take a look.

Comment: I agree this is decent approach. Maybe your specific interface needs rethinking to reduce the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good to me. If you have performance problems with it you must have really big number of rows, in which case you really want to rethink the UI. That said, you could actually try optimizing calculations by subscribing to *qty* and *selected* observables and changing your totals based on old and new values for one book. The code below illustrates the idea but is not a complete solution. Also, standard knockoutjs observable doesn't have *lastValue* attribute, so you would have to implement it by yourself ([here](http://pervasivecode.blogspot.com/2011/07/knockoutjs-making-observable-that-fits.html) is an example of how you would do it).

```
function book(...){
    var self = this;
    ...
    self.qty.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if(self.selected()){
            //grandTotal is regular observable, not a computed one
            var grandTotal = rootViewModel.grandTotal(); 
            grandTotal = grandTotal - self.qty.lastValue() + newValue;
            rootViewModel(grandTotal);
        }            
    }
}
```

For student level subtotals you will need to pass student viewmodel as a parameter to book constructor:

```
function book(student, name, qty){
    var self = this;
    ...
    self.qty.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if(self.selected()){
            //student.noOfBooks is regular observable, not a computed one
            var noOfBooks = student.noOfBooks(); 
            noOfBooks = noOfBooks - self.qty.lastValue() + newValue;
            student.noOfBooks(noOfBooks);
        }            
    }
}
```

You will probably need to change student constructor to something like this:

```
function student(name, books /*array of plain object, not view models*/){
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.noOfBooks = ko.observable()
    self.books = ko.utils.arrayMap(books, function(b){
        return new book(self, b.name, b.qty);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, this looks good for root model, can you please throw some idea how can we do that for 'student' level subtotals? In my actual requirement, I need to handle around 1000 rows having 10 to 20 sub rows under each, in total 10,000 to 20,000. So small improvement in performance also helps.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover student level subtotals. This is still not a complete solution, just an idea.